# Uploading a zip file to a database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, zip

I am using Entity Framework as part of a school/course project where users should be allowed to upload files or directories. If it's a directory it has to be zipped(I got hold of DotNetZip) but I am not sure of how convert the zip file into a `byte[]`. Also should I store the zip in the temp directory and delete it once it has been saved?

Comment: Storing files in a database is a really bad practice.

Comment: @DanielMann it is just a project/exam, we have all to make a kind of learning portal where students can upload docs & notes so that others can benefit. It will never actually be implemented; it is really just to make us work out the problem(and using stackoverflow is allowed, even encouraged). But I will keep that in mind. Any suggestions for a better solution?

Comment: Instead of storing files in a database, store a URI to the file and store the file in the filesystem. Databases aren't meant for file storage, and what it gets you in a real-world scenario is a database that's unnecessarily large and takes a lot more time to back up / restore.

Comment: @DanielMann Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. I start my intern-ship in a few weeks so anything I can learn before hand is a massive help.

Comment: scalability? what about a multi-server environment? you can't just save to the filesystem on the local hard drive

Comment: @bboyle1234 Of course not but at the time I asked the question I was still doing my course on learning to program and it was for a school project. Perhaps the question is a little too specific but at that time I didn't know any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples, you can save the zip file to a memory stream without writing it to any temporary file:

```
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
    zip.AddFile("7440-N49th.png");
    zip.AddFile("2008_Annual_Report.pdf");        
    zip.Save(stream);
}

byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: an't believe I missed that! Thank you.